# Python convention: function constructor for a private class

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have noticed this in Python's threading module source:

```
def Event(*args, **kwargs):
  return _Event(*args, **kwargs)

class _Event(_Verbose):
  ...
```

Am I correct in assuming this is an attempt in mimicking a "sealed" class (c#) or a "final" class (java) in other languages? Is this a common pattern in Python? Are there any other approaches to this problem in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I like this choice of identifiers. It is conventional to start class names with an uppercase letter, so you'd think that you could say `isinstance(x, Event)`, but you can't. I think a name such as `make_event` that unambiguously identifies the function as a function would have been better.

This issue has already been [discussed](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-September/082117.html) on the mailing list, where the BDFL [states](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-September/082144.html):

> This started out as an experiment in API
>   design, where I tried to make things look as much like the similar
>   Java API as possible (I didn't want to invent yet anotherwobbly
>   wheel). I specifically wanted these *not* to be classes so that people
>   wouldn't start subclassing them. At the time PEP-8 wasn't well
>   established (if at all) and I wanted the factory functions to look
>   like classes. I think in 2.7 / 3.1 we can change the factory functions
>   to conform to PEP-8 (leaving the old names in for a couple of
>   release).

The change he mentioned hasn't been done yet, but I think it's pretty safe to say that nowadays the naming scheme is seen as misguided and should not be proliferated.

You're right when you say that these factory functions were introduced to mimic a sealed class. The BDFL [says](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-September/082186.html)

> Allowing them to be subclassed makes it harder to replace them on some
>   platforms with equivalent but faster implementations.

I don't think this scheme is too common. Most of the time, there is no incentive to replace classes with equivalent implementations, and if a class is not designed for subclassing, you can mention that in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I should have only tried searching harder before asking.

Answer (score 1):

That would seem to be the idea, but obviously it's still perfectly possible to inherit from the classes if you want (even if they were in a separate module, you can do `type(Event())` to get a reference. It presumably is just intended to make people think before subclassing them.

It's not a common pattern in Python. There are very few things that we specifically discourage inheriting from.

Comment: I have noticed that it is practically impossible to actually make access to a particular object impossible in Python.  If one object has a reference to another, you can follow some access path that gets to that reference.

Comment: It's often suggested that subclassing should be explicit, only if the class is intended to be subclassed, as it is often more appropriate to create a container where subclassing would be otherwise possible (but was not intended). Since in the mentioned languages this can be achieved by a single keyword, it seems this pattern is followed more often. However in Python there is no such equivalent and a trick like this is the closest one can get. I was wondering whether this is appropriate convention to copy and if perhaps there is some other way of explicitly stating following by other means.

Comment: PEP 8 says: "The naming conventions of Python's library are a bit of a mess" and "Function names should be lowercase". Since `Event` is undoubtedly a function, its name breaks the style guide. It's not that harmful (the documentation makes it clear that it is a function), but I think you shouldn't copy this naming scheme. See also http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-September/082117.html

Comment: @mosmbelly: The convention in Python is to not to prevent subclassing. After all, maybe someone in the future will have a brilliant idea for how to extend your class a bit. If there's a good reason why subclassing it is a bad idea, mention it in the docs.

Comment: Generally true, but in this case the module was designed by GvR to disallow subclasses, see the quotes in my answer